# What the Angular brackets, [] () {}, bind and when to use which

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I see the brackets are used for data binding, but what's the difference?

The below snippets are the ones I use frequently. But mostly taken as documented without understanding why.

- `[class]="myclass"`
- `(ngModelChange)="mymodel"`
- `[(ngModel)]="mymodel2"`
- `<ion-input placeholder="{{'INPUT_TEXT' | translate}}"/>`
- `<button>{{'BUTTON_TEXT'|translate}}</button>`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All the above syntax can be found at this [page](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) of the Angular Documentation. You can read up more about Angular's Template Syntax on other blogs if you wish.

1)  `[class]="myclass"`

The square brackets [...] represent the [one-way](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) property binding from the component logic (data) to the view (target element).

2) `(ngModelChange)`

This represents [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding-event), which allows the target to listen for certain events such as clicks and keypresses.

3) `[(ngModel)]="mymodel2"`

This represents [two-way data binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---), which combines the above two syntaxes. The property's data is displayed on the view, and at the same time, the property will be updated when the user makes any changes.

4) `<ion-input placeholder="{{'INPUT_TEXT' | translate}}"/>`

You are simply importing another component into your current component, and the `placeholder` attribute is assigned the value of the component property `INPUT_TEXT` through [template interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-).

The [pipe operator (|)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-pipe-operator---) allows you to carry out transformation of the displayed value. Pipes accept an input and, return the respective transformed value

5) Similar to 4.

Answer (score 5):

- `[class]="myclass"` -> one way property binding, changes in variable `class` in the `.ts` will be reflected in the view. (Binding from typescript to HTML)
- `(ngModelChange)="mymodel"` -> one way event binding, when a `modelChange` event occurs, do whatever is present in the expression, (one way binding from HTML to typescript)
- `[(ngModel)]`="mymodel2" -> two way binding, changes in the variable `mymode2` within typescript will be reflected in the view, if any change occurs in the view, like in an input, then that change will be reflected in typescript too.
- `<ion-input placeholder="{{'INPUT_TEXT' | translate}}"/>` -> interploation, as an when the value of data within `"{{}}"` will change, the value of the placeholder attribute will be updated
- `<button>{{'BUTTON_TEXT'|translate}}</button>` -> again, interpolation, just not bound to any property.